# How to manipulate Pivot control to looks linear?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, pivot

I have a pivot control with 3 items, I want when it reaches to the third item, not swipe to the first (as an example, when you reach to the last picture in built in photo hub app.)

So I thought I can handle it by hand, when he is accessing the first item from the third one, I ignore it and select the third as `SelectedItem`. But there is no such `SelectionChanging` event and just `SelectionChanged`:

```
private void pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

How can I have a pivot with linear appearance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectionChanged event can also do your work, try something like this-

```
  private void pivoteSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        Pivot pivot = (Pivot)sender;

        if (lastselectedIndex == 2 && pivot.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            pivot.SelectedIndex= 2;
            return;
        }
        else if (lastselectedIndex == 0 && pivot.SelectedIndex == 2)
          {
            pivot.SelectedIndex= 0;
            return;
        }


        lastselectedIndex = pivote.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

Here SelectedIndex is 0 for first PivotItem and 2 for 3rd Item.
and set lastselectedIndex variable to 0 on start and create it from outside this method.